# ¿Posibles anagramas de ese string en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Intenté realizar un código que me permitiera obtener anagramas con un `Math.random` pero al final no logro llegar a la solución.

La idea es hacer una función que, a partir de un String recibido como parámetro, genere todos los posibles anagramas de ese String y retorne un arreglo con ellos.

También sería ideal eliminar las palabras duplicadas.

Dejo mi código para que me den una guía. :

```
const anagrams = allAnagrams('abc');

console.log(anagrams); // [ 'abc', 'acb', 'bac', 'bca', 'cab', 'cba' ]

var allAnagrams = function(string, array, index) {

    var numerodeCombinacionesPosibles = Math.pow(string.length, string.length)
    var array = [string]
    index=1;
    var iterable;

    for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        iterable = array[j]
    }

    while (index < numerodeCombinacionesPosibles && iterable !== array[index] ) {

        array.push(array[index-1].split("").sort(function() { return Math.random() - 0.5 }).join(""));
        index++;

    }
}
```

Comment: Esto es un error: `var numerodeCombinacionesPosibles = Math.pow(string.length, string.length)` debes usar un **combinatorio de n en n** (n factorial) y estás usando n a la n.

Comment: Mira tu ejemplo inicial tiene 6 elementos `3! = 6` mientras que `3^3 = 9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obtener todas las permutaciones de un string (recursivo).

```js
function permutaciones(string, raiz = '') {
    if (string.length == 1) {     // último caso
        return [raiz + string];
    } else {
        let res = [];
        for (let i=0; i < string.length; i++) {
            // ir tomando cada uno de los caracteres como raiz
            // como string va lo que está antes+después de ese caracter
            // obtener recursivamente el array de permutaciones
            res.push(
                 ...permutaciones(string.substr(0,i) + string.substr(i+1), string[i])
                    .map(x=>raiz+x)
            );
        }
        return res;
    }
}

function distinct(array) { //eliminar repetidos en array
    return [...new Set(array)];
}

function anagramas(string) { // anagramas == permutaciones no repetidas
    return distinct(permutaciones(string));
}


// ------ Ejemplo ------ //
var resultado = anagramas('abc');

console.log(resultado); // [ 'abc', 'acb', 'bac', 'bca', 'cab', 'cba' ]
```

Básicamente recorre cada caracter del string. Va llamando recursivamente con ese caracter como *raíz* (inalterable), y el *resto del string* (lo que está antes + lo que está después) como parámetro.

La función va devolviendo el array formado por la raíz + cada una de las permutaciones obtenidas recursivamente.

> [image: arbol de permutaciones]

Cuando sólo queda 1 caracter, devuelve el array de 1 único elemento de raiz + caracter.
para obtener el array de permutaciones.

La función `permutaciones()` obtiene todas las posibilidades, incluso repetidas. Con `distinct()` se eliminan duplicados.

Answer (score 1):

Código que resuelve los anagramas con fuerza bruta con `Math.ramdom()`.

```js
let cadena = 'abc';

// la cantidad de combinaciones posibles es un factorial
// si la cadena es abc, su longitud es 3
// numero de posibles combinaciones 3! = 3 x 2 x 1 = 6
let numeroCombinaciones = factorial(cadena.length);

let anagramas = [];

// repetir hasta que se encuentren todos los anagramas
while(anagramas.length != numeroCombinaciones){
  // obtener un anagrama
  let anagrama = combinar(cadena);
  // si no existe en el arreglo, agregarlo
  if(!anagramas.includes(anagrama)) anagramas.push(anagrama);
 
 }

console.log(anagramas);



function combinar(cadena){
  // crear un arreglo a partir de los caracteres de la cadena
  let arreglo = Array.from(cadena);
  
  // iterar el arreglo
  for(i = 0 ; i < arreglo.length; i++){
    // generar un número aleatorio entre 0 y arreglo.length -1
    // si la cadena tiene tres caracteres los números estarán entre
    // 0 y 2
    let index  = Math.floor(Math.random() * arreglo.length);
    
    // intercambiar el caracter en la posición i
    // con el caracter en la posición index
    let temp = arreglo[i];
    arreglo[i] = arreglo[index];
    arreglo[index] = temp;
  
  }
  // convertir el arreglo en una cadena
  return arreglo.join('');

}


function factorial (n) {
    let total = 1; 
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        total = total * i; 
    }
    return total; 
}
```